# How to split a row into new rows for every new entry of datetime?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, nlp

I want to split the text and form a new row whenever a DateTime occurred. Raw dataframe looks like

```
Patient_id   |        Issue  
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1           |12-02-2018 12:15:52 -abc-Patient have headache 20-02-2018 2:15:52 -abc- Previous medication 
             |had some side effects 20-03-2018 5:30:52 -abc- Patient got cured xyz worked well.
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------              
 2           | 19-02-2018 2:50:52 -cbf- cbf is allergic def medicine and 
             |  have a fever with a body ache 25-02-2018 2:50:52 -cbf-
             |  Patient got cured by def medicine.
```

I tried the following but not getting expected results

```
df = pd.DataFrame(re.split('(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} - .*\s+)',df['Issue'], re.DOTALL),columns = ['Issue'])
```

Expected result

```
Patient_id   |        Issue  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1           |12-02-2018 12:15:52 -abc-Patient have headache 
             | 20-02-2018 2:15:52 -abc- Previous medication had some side effects.
             |20-03-2018 5:30:52 -abc-Patient got cured xyz worked well.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------              
 2            | 19-02-2018 2:50:52 -cbf- cbf is allergic def medicine and have fever with bodyache
              |25-02-2018 2:50:52 -cbf-Patient got cured by def medicine.
```

Then I tried to split the information into different columns like Number, date, name, and issues respectively.

```
df = df.Issue.str.split('-',n=3)

df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.tolist(),columns=['Number', 'Date','Name', 'Issue'])
```

Expected final output

```
Patient_id|Name|Date of admission  |Issue  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         |abc |12-02-2018 12:15:52|Patient have headache 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         |abc |20-02-2018 2:15:52 |Previous medication had some side effects.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         |abc |20-03-2018 5:30:52 |Patient got cured xyz worked well.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                
2         |cbf |19-02-2018 2:50:52 |cbf is allergic def medicine and have to fever with a body ache
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2         |cbf |25-02-2018 2:50:52 |Patient got cured by def medicine.
```

Answer (score 1):

This assume that the Name/Issue does not contain any digits:

```
s = df.set_index('Patent_id').Issue

s.str.extractall('(?P<Date>\d*-\d*-\d* \d*:\d*:\d*)\s+-(?P<Name>\w*)-(?P<Issue>[\D\s]*)')
```

gives:

```
                    Date                Name    Issue
Patent_id   match           
1           0       12-02-2018 12:15:52 abc     Patient have headache
            1       20-02-2018 2:15:52  abc     Previous medication had some side effects
            2       20-03-2018 5:30:52  abc     Patient got cured xyz worked well.
2           0       19-02-2018 2:50:52  cbf     cbf is allergic def medicine and have a fever...
            1       25-02-2018 2:50:52  cbf     Patient got cured by def medicine.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the split with this regex

`(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}[ ]\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}(?:(?!\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}[ ]\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})[\S\s])*)`

Note that the timestamp has variable digits 1 or 2

https://regex101.com/r/e9kPsd/1

Expanded

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      \d{2} - \d{2} - \d{4} [ ] \d{1,2} : \d{1,2} : \d{1,2} 
      (?:
           (?! \d{2} - \d{2} - \d{4} [ ] \d{1,2} : \d{1,2} : \d{1,2} )
           [\S\s] 
      )*
 )                             # (1 end)
```